# San Marco Concor -- is there a "pocket" in non-cutout version?

Tags: saddle

I've read that San Marco Regale instead of having cutout implemented a relief zone (see: [Regale review](http://www.bikeradar.com/gear/category/components/saddles/product/review-selle-san-marco-regale-racing-team-44465)). So visually it is like non-cutout saddle, however *something-which-works-like-a-cutout* is present.

I cannot find a confirmation, that San Marco Concor (non-cutout version) also has such feature, from  [technical presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmulxkUyq3c) it is obvious there is some kind of "pocket" (for more foam, or for different kind of foam) exactly where the cutout comes in cutout (arrowhead) version. However what it is for?

Could someone who had such saddle in hand (personally) could confirm or deny this? I.e. **the question is** -- does non-cutout (non-arrowhead) version of Concor have some kind of pocket to work as some kind of cutout (relief spot)?

*Usually the pocket is used as term to describe curved saddle --- but NOT here, here I use it in sense of a built-in channel, or hidden cutout.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [REGALe Carbon FX information page](http://www.sellesanmarco.it/en/Collezione/Saddles/39/Regale%20Carbon%20FX.html) has an "i" button, that when clicked, loads a list of features. This includes "COREZONE", which is the feature referred to in the review you linked to.

On the [Concor Carbon FX information page](http://www.sellesanmarco.it/en/Collezione/Saddles/239/Concor%20Racing%20Team.html), I clicked on the "i" button but did not see "COREZONE" listed for any of them. If the feature isn't specifically listed, I think it's safe to assume that the relief zone is not there.

I checked a few different Concor models and didn't see "COREZONE" listed for any of them, but I didn't go through the entire list. If you're interested in a specific model, click the "i" button on its specific page to see if it's included.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't even notice, this feature is officially listed.